# How to remove or hide the navigation bar in the "View all" page of related list in Salesforce

Tags: related-list, list-view

When you select ‘View All’ on any related list, and the list view screen appears. there is a navigation at the top of each that when you select the previous link opens a list view that allows the user to view more accounts than just theirs.We want to disable, remove, or hide this navigation from the particular user

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! It sounds like you have a Sharing Settings problem. It's also unclear why you've tagged Apex, Visualforce, Aura, and Web Components. Are you trying to find a programmatic solution to your problem? Is there a reason you can't fix your security settings? Please read about [ask] and the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). We'll be happy to help you out after you [edit] your question to include more detail.